# Assistance with ruby def

Tags: python, ruby

So, I'm new to ruby and very curious about it. I'm comming from python. in python I would do this to see if something was present in a dictionary.

```
dictionary = dict()
dictionary['key'] = 5
def inDictionary(key):
    if key in dictionary:
       execute code
    else:
        other code
```

Rather simple for me, in ruby on the other hand how would I do this? i've been trying stuff like

```
dictionary = Hash.new
dictionary['key'] = 5
def isDictionary(key)
    if dictionary.has_key?(key)
       puts 'has key'
    end
end
```

I get the error, isDictionary undefined local variable or method "dictionary". What am I doing wrong, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Thats because the scope of dictionary changes when you call it inside the isDictionary method. I would recommend creating a class dictionary and a isDictionary method within it so that all the instances that you spawn through that class with have isDictionary available to them .Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ruby, `def`, `class`, and `module` keywords start new local scopes. That means `dictionary` variable (defined as a local) is not accessible in this `isDictionary` function, as the latest has its own scope.

Of course, you can mark your variable with `$` sigil to make it global instead, but you'd better not to. The whole point of Ruby is making objects - collections of data and methods to process/transform that data - as 'innate' as possible.

In this case the most natural solution would be to define class Dictionary, make dictionary its instance variable (with `@` sigil), then access this variable in class method isDictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@dictionar­y = Hash.­new
@dictionar­y['key'] = 5
def isDic­tionary(ke­y)
    if @dict­ionary.has­_key?(key)­
       puts 'has key'
    end
end

isDictionary("key")
```

What I have done is I have enhanced the scope of the `dictionary` variable by converting it into a instance variable `@dictionary`.